# How to prevent splashscreen to auto hide on android using Cordova splashscreen plugin (ionic)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a way to control the time my splashscreen shows. Since I have to download data before the user can interact with the UI, this time is not fixed.
My problem is that I am not able to prevent the splash screen from being autohide on Android, on iOS I did it adding this to my `config.xml`

```xml
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

this is my `config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.example.my" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>my example</name>
  <description>
        an example app
    </description>

  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
      <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen"/>
          <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
  <plugin name="com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions" spec="~0.6.5"/>
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.8.1">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.1.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.7.2"/>
</widget>
```

Is there a special param/feature that I have to add to my `config.xml`?

Edit:
If I change the `SplashScreenDelay` value, it also broke the time the splashscreen takes to hide on ios after I send `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this adding different preferences inside each platform tags

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#93bc26" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="50000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0"/>
</platform>
```

**Edit:**
This is the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <widget id="com.example.my" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>my example</name>
  <description>an example app
  </description>

<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#93bc26" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="50000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
</platform>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
<plugin name="com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions" spec="~0.6.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.7.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.8.2">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.0" />
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your complete config.xml again? I'm having a similar issue, but the changes I've made doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @Birk I added my complete config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the next parameter:

```xml
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can gather from your `config.xml` that your are using `cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.1.0` you should probably update the plugin.

Reading the [Release Notes 3.2.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#320-feb-09-2016) of the plugin should already give you the information you are needing. As far as I can see, there are two `bug fixes` in the `3.2.0` release, concerning your issue...

Updating from `CLI` should give you the most recent plugin version:

```
cordova plugins remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Comment: Weird, cordova cli doesn't say it is a new version than mine.

Comment: Try out this: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.0 --save`. Cordova made same changes to their CLI, I am not used to it yet

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
```

Remove this , which sets a max delay and provokes a white screen if app hasn't loaded

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

On your app.component's constructor

```
 constructor(
        public platform: Platform,
        public statusBar: StatusBar,
        public splashScreen: SplashScreen,

      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      splashScreen.hide();    
    }
}
```

And you import it from the ionic-native plugin

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
```